# TIFF file to Google My Maps

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, google-maps

I am trying to convert the TIFF file I have been working on to upload to Google My Maps but cannot find a file type in the export dropdown that will work. Any suggestions?

Comment: More details please on what you're trying to do.

Comment: You need to put much more effort into writing your question. I don't know what software you used for creating the TIFF and what software has the export menu that you are talking about. Try again, and perhaps someone will know how to help you :)

Comment: I am using qgis. The tiff is originally the Centre for Ecology and Hydrology 2020 10m raster of land cover (LCM) of a portion of Norfolk and Suffolk, UK. I corrected it using serval to make it more accurate and I wanted to add it to google maps so I could share it with some people. Unfortunately I can't export it in a file type that google maps will accept.

Answer (score 1):

The choose a file to import option, suggests CSV, XLSX, KML, or GPX are the only options for imports.

[image: Google My Maps choose a file to import]

KML supports rasters, but the [help](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024836?hl=en&ref_topic=3024924) tells us that:

> KML files may not import all their data. The data includes:

> ...

> Image and screen overlays

So I suspect you're out of luck, and that only vector formats are supported.  You'll need to vectorize the TIFF, not merely export as.